# Error as Element is not clickable at point in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, automation

Dom structure :

```
 <li class="slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger--click slds-m-left--
  x-small" data-aura-rendered-by="534:20;a">
 <!--render facet: 537:20;a-->
 <!--
 render facet: 541:20;a--><button class="bare slds-button uiButton 
 forceHeaderButton oneUserProfileCardTrigger" aria-live="off" type="button" 
 data-aura-rendered-by="184:190;a" data-aura-class="uiButton 
 forceHeaderButton 
 oneUserProfileCardTrigger"><!--render facet: 185:190;a--><!--render facet: 
 187:190;a-->
 <div class="tooltipTrigger tooltip-trigger uiTooltip" aria-describedby="tt-
 for-174:190;a" tabindex="-1" data-aura-rendered-by="179:190;a" data-aura-
 class="uiTooltip">
 <span data-aura-rendered-by="171:190;a" class="uiImage" 
 data-aura-class="uiImage"><img data-aura-rendered-by="169:190;a" 
 src="https://c.ap5.content.force.com/profilephoto/005/T/1" 
 class="profileTrigger" alt="">
 </span><span class="tooltip-invisible" 
 role="tooltip" id="tt-for-174:190;a" data-aura-rendered-by="181:190;a">View 
 profile</span>
 </div></button><!--render facet: 543:20;a-->
 </li>
```

i tried these lines of code for Logout :

First click on Logout symbol:

```
   WebDriverWait wait3 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); 
   driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@class = 'profileTrigger']")).click();
   JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
   /*exe1.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", newbt);*/
   jse.executeScript("scroll(250, 0)");
```

second click on Logout button :

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@class = 
       'profile-link-label logout uiOutputURL']"));
```

I am getting error as Element is not clickable at point.

Comment: o_0... which code we have to send you? Please, provide more details including full log

Comment: @FieryCat, above Full Dom Structure. i want to write a code for logout . i tried above code. It is giving error . Error is Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not clickable at point (1231, 25). Other element would receive the click: <div class="panel slds-modal slds-fade-in-open" aria-labelledby="title_2378:0" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-aura-rendered-by="2394:0" style="opacity: 1;">...</div>
  (Session info: chrome=59.0.3071.104) Please help me .

Comment: @FieryCat Be prepared to hear from OP that you have to login in his website with your own credentials :) Thanks

Comment: The element path which you are using should be unique. Please use the different path.

Comment: @Mounika i tried with all paths .Please send code for clicking log out button. DOM Structure is there above. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

1.Use scrollTo element by selector - this will ensure element is visible:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='oneUserProfileCardTrigger']"));
((JavascriptExecutor) driver)
    .executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element);
```

2.Always use delay or wait after scroll before click. It takes time for browser.

3.If nothing helps - use javascript click. Bad solution as it not like real user do, but will work always:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='oneUserProfileCardTrigger']"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver)
    .executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

Comment: I tried with all locators . Please help me with some other code. I am getting error like element is not clickable at point. I tried with all locators.Please help me with some other code. Dom structure is there above.

Comment: @SrieedherSanthakumar ok, the reason that element is not clickable: it is not visible or other element (like modal or something else) overlap it. The final solution might be not use selenium click but javascript click - not the best one but should work. Update my answer with this option (#3)

Comment: @SrieedherSanthakumar I have add the code. Please see option #3 in body of answer

Comment: in that  there is no id in it. Only class name and link text is there.I tried with both . Both are not working properly. I will try with  javascript  executor and i will update you. Please help me with some other code for log out. Above i send full DOM Structure for Log out.Please help me.

Comment: @SrieedherSanthakumar here is the final code with your selectors:
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='oneUserProfileCardTrigger']"));
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver)
        .executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);

Comment: i tried the code. It is giving error as Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[@class = 'oneUserProfile‌​‌​CardTrigger']"} .Please send me any other code.

Answer (score 0):

@SrieedherSanthakumar
I have few that would like to clarify first, whether or not are you dependent on wait call. Like you are clicking on something and want to wait for something and then process with your second click ?

If so, you might have to modify your first call something like below :

```
 WebDriverWait wait3 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); 
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@class = 'profileTrigger']")).click();
    WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));
       JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
       /*exe1.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", newbt);*/
       jse.executeScript("scroll(250, 0)");
```

once you have waited for your page to be load or expected id is visible then proceed with your second call. I am not able to see whether you are waiting for your object in the first call to load since you are clicking on **profileTrigger** before moving forward with your second call.

Comment: @Gupta, WebDriverWait wait3 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20); 
       driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@class = 'profileTrigger']")).click(); It is not clicking .After clicking save script is in same page. Please suggest any other measure.

Comment: It is your code, only I have added a wait condition in that. You need to check the property in that case of element you are trying to click too. Try to use class, id or proper xpath in that case.

Comment: @Gupta, i tried with class name and link text is only there. Please help me with your any other code. I am getting the error like element is not clickable at point (1231, 25). Other element would receive the click: <div class="panel slds-modal slds-fade-in-open" aria-labelledby="title_2038:0" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-aura-rendered-by="2054:0" style="opacity: 1;">...</div>

Comment: @SrieedherSanthakumar

Try with this : 

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'tooltipTrigger tooltip-trigger uiTooltip')]")).click();

"tooltipTrigger tooltip-trigger uiTooltip", this should be name of your div class which you are trying to click.

If this does not work start a chat because i will be needing more details and page source.

Comment: @anushul gupta, now element is locating iam trying to log out.

Comment: @SrieedherSanthakumar you need to use the same way as mentioned earlier, pass the class name for the div you are trying to locate and do up vote in case answer was helpful and solved your issue.

Comment: please send me code for logout. I tried with all the locators.please send code . DOM structure is there.

Comment: @SrieedherSanthakumar there is no dom structure for logout above and it should be pretty straight forward like the obe bellow just check in dom element whether its a div/span/ul/li element based on that modify the below call it should work : driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'tooltipT‌​rigger tooltip-trigger uiTooltip')]")).click();

Comment: i tried this code driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class,'tooltipT‌​‌​rigger tooltip-trigger uiTooltip')]")).click();  This code is giving me error as unable to locate an element . It is not clicking Log out button . Can you please send code for Log out button. I tried with all codes.

Comment: Did you read the comments, what I am trying to suggest you?? I have given you an example and you need to make it use according to your DOM structure.