# code to click a log out button in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium

I tried the following code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='https://c.ap5.content.force.com/profilephoto/005/T/1']")).click();
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
jse.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", newbt);


//clicking Log out button.
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'profile-link-label logoutuiOutputURL')]")).click();
```

I am getting the following error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: Element is not 
 clickable at point (1231, 25). Other element would receive the click: <div 
 class="panel slds-modal slds-fade-in-open" aria-labelledby="title_2099:0" 
 tabindex="-1" role="dialog" data-aura-rendered-by="2115:0" style="opacity: 
 1;">...</div>
```

Dom structure  for log out :

```
<li class="slds-dropdown-trigger slds-dropdown-trigger--click slds-m-left--
x-small" data-aura-rendered-by="534:20;a">
<!--render facet: 537:20;a-->
<!--render facet: 541:20;a-->
<button class="bare slds-button uiButton forceHeaderButton 
oneUserProfileCardTrigger" aria-live="off" type="button" data-aura-rendered 
-by="184:190;a" data-aura-class="uiButton forceHeaderButton 
oneUserProfileCardTrigger"><!--render facet: 185:190;a-->
<!--render facet: 
187:190;a--><div class="tooltipTrigger tooltip-trigger uiTooltip" aria-
describedby="tt-for-174:190;a" tabindex="-1" data-aura-rendered-
by="179:190;a" 
data-aura-class="uiTooltip"><span data-aura-rendered-by="171:190;a" 
class="uiImage" data-aura-class="uiImage">
<img data-aura-rendered-by="169:190;a" 
src="https://c.ap5.content.force.com/profilephoto/005/T/1" 
class="profileTrigger" alt=""></span><span class="tooltip-invisible" 
role="tooltip" id="tt-for-174:190;a" data-aura-rendered-by="181:190;a">View 
profile</span></div>
</button>
<!--render facet: 543:20;a-->
</li>
```

Can someone explain why this isn't working and possibly suggest a fix? Thank you.

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: is the logout button visible?

Comment: @santhosh, yes it is visible.

Comment: @santhosh, please login into salesforce. url is https://login.salesforce.com/.user name is  sriee93@force.com. password is 
Sriee678$.pls use this credentials. For log out please send me code .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error as Element is not clickable at point in selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44646049/error-as-element-is-not-clickable-at-point-in-selenium)

Comment: @alexey, yes. Element is not going to Log out button.

Comment: whats the verification code delivered to your mobile?

Comment: @santhosh, 17119

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that there is another element on front of the log out button. Without seeing the actual page being tested, there are a few things that could be wrong, but here are some potential solutions.

- Maximize the selenium webdriver window, as a smaller window could be resizing an element to overlap your logout button.
- Inspect the webpage (right click > inspect) and see what element is overlapping the logout button.

Answer (score 0):

Try clicking using javascript executor

```
WebElement e = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'profile-link-label logout  uiOutputURL')]"));
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", e);
```

Hope it will help you

Comment: above code giving error as Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[contains(@class, 'profile-link-label logout  uiOutputURL')]"} .

Comment: NoSuchElement exception comes when the locater you are using doesnt exist on the UI. Could you please share the  html code of logout button. Just do inspect element of logout button and copy the html code and paste here

Answer (score 0):

Click on the username so that logout button will become visible.

```
driver.findElement(by.xpath("//div[@id='userNavButton']/span")).click();
```

Now click on the logout button.

```
driver.findElement(by.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Logout')]")).click();
```

Hope this helps you. Thanks.

Comment: kindly delete all your comments for this answer.., it looks more messy